# To communicate between two bluetooth devices is pairing between them is necessary?

Tags: linux, sockets, bluetooth

In general, two communicate between bluetooth devices, first we perform a bluetooth pairing between two devices and then starts further communication between them.

My problem scenario is simply to transfer a hello packet from one bluetooth device to another bluetooth device.

For this i am planning to use sockets programming technique i.e. RFCOMM sockets.
I got some help about this from http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

So, my query is do we require bluetooth pairing between two devices before initiating communication with RFCOMM socket connection. 
Or does 48 bits device address is only necessary to transfer some data packet from one bluetooth device to other and bluetooth pairing could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not.

Bluetooth device can be in one of the four modes:
Broadcaster
Observer
Peripheral
Central

In broadcaster mode device can only send advertisement messages. This includes name and HwID.
In Observer mode device can only receive advertisement messages.
Peripheral = Broadcaster + can take in connect requests
Central = Observer + can send out connect requests.

If you have an application which does not want to connect use first two modes above.

Please let me know if this addresses your question.